# Xen 4.2.xx compatibility with Fedora 17

Tags: compatibility, xen, fedora-17

I know that Fedora 17 ships with Xen 4.1.xx, but is it compatible with Xen 4.2.xx and later versions? I have searched online and found nothing either supporting or denying the fact. If it is compatible then why does yum package update utility does not pick up the updates?

P.S. I am working with Fedora 17 for testing some kernel modules, and thus do not want to upgrade the kernel version.

Comment: Fedora 17 is legacy and probably won't receive updates for now. If it is possible, update it.

Comment: But the packages should be updated?

Comment: Here on Fedora 20 I have the bleeding edge Xen 4.2

Comment: There might be some compatibility issues with some of the kernel modules that I am testing, and thus do not want to disturb the linux kernel version.

Comment: Oh, you should specify it in the questionar then.